# How to add multiple shortcode in one functions?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I had this wordpress functions

```
function randm() { 
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'post',
   'orderby'=> 'rand', 'category_name' => 'Motor',
   'posts_per_page' => 1, );
  wp_reset_postdata(); 
} 
 
else { $string .= 'no posts found'; } return $string; }
 
add_shortcode('randm','randm'); 
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

In the code above if I type `[randm]` will show the post from "Motor" category, I want to add multiple category in there and multiple shortcode for every different category how to do that?

Comment: Something is missing in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be incomplete, anyway:
You need to use shortcode attritubes, if I'm understanding you right.

```
function randm($atts) {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'orderby'=> 'rand', 
        'category_name' => $atts['category'], 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    ); 
    /// ... your code 
}
```

You can use this as shortcode:

```
[randm category="Motor"]
```

If you want to use multiple categories, you can explode the string:

```
function randm($atts) {
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'post', 
        'orderby'=> 'rand', 
        'category_name' => explode(', ', $atts['category']), 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    ); 
    /// ... your code 
 }
```

and use

```
[randm category="Motor, Second"]
```

If you want to make sure a default value exist you can use

```
function randm($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'category' => 'Motor',
    ), $atts); 
    // Remaining code
}
```

Comment: Awesome, problem solved GBU, thank you so much sir!!